# could not pull the data if it is null in mongo and node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nodejs-server

```js
var myquery = { code: code, display_name: display_name,"main_page.sliders.web.id":wid };
    var newvalues = {
      $pull: {
        "main_page.sliders.web": {"id":wid }, 
        "main_page.sliders.mobile": {id: mid }
      },
    }
    dbo.collection("industries").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, async function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, response: err.message, statusbar: err })
      }
      res.json({ success: true, statuscode: 200, response: result });
      db.close();
    });
  });
```

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "622a457fbc875bc6795ceeb6"
    },
    "code": "FO",
    "display_name": "Film & OTT",
    "caption": "Jobs in Film & OTT Industries",
    "display_order": 1,
    "main_page": {
      "page_name": "Film & OTT",
      "slug": "film_ott",
      "title": "Film & OTT ",
      "SEO": {
        "title": "Film OTT",
        "description": "",
        "keywords": ""
      },
      "sliders": {
        "web": [],
        "mobile": []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "622a459ebc875bc6795ceebb"
    },
    "code": "VO",
    "display_name": "Voice & Singing",
    "caption": "Jobs in Singing & Voice Over Industries",
    "display_order": 21,
    "main_page": {
      "page_name": "Voice & Singing",
      "slug": "voice_singing",
      "title": "Voice & Singing",
      "SEO": {
        "title": "Voice & Singing",
        "description": "",
        "keywords": ""
      },
      "sliders": {
        "web": [
          {
            "id": "2",
            "url": "www.rama.com",
            "display_order": "2",
            "title": "venkata industries",
            "caption": "just go",
            "link": "venkata",
            "description": "money matters"
          }
        ],
        "mobile": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "url": "www.rama.com",
            "display_order": "1",
            "title": "venkata industries",
            "caption": "aha",
            "link": "radhesyam",
            "description": "just do it"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

here I am trying to delete the objects in the mobile or web array and I have made id as unique in both of them so when try to pull and when it is null means there is no object it wont pull from other DOCUMENTS as well any idea?

can we ignore and iterate other documents if one is null even though it is unique key constraint

thanks in advance

```js
{
    "success": false,
    "response": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: TalentKind.industries index: main_page.sliders.mobile.id_1 dup key: { main_page.sliders.mobile.id: null }",
    "statusbar": {
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "keyPattern": {
            "main_page.sliders.mobile.id": 1
        },
        "keyValue": {
            "main_page.sliders.mobile.id": null
        }
    }
}

this is the error I am getting @YuTing and as I said I made main_page.sliders.web.id_1 as unique
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a unique index on the main_page.sliders.mobile.id key. As a result, it should not be left as null. You can do so by removing the unique key from the index.
[image: check here]

update:
try by adding partialIndex

```
db.getCollection('tests_copy').createIndex(
   {"main_page.sliders.mobile.id": 1},
   {unique: true, partialFilterExpression: {"main_page.sliders.mobile.id": {$type: 2}}}
);
```

Comment: exactly my point . And I cant take out unique key still want do so ..,any ideas ?